# Jquery validation multiple tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, tabs, jquery-validate

I'm new to jQuery and I'm trying to use it and the validation plugin (http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) to create a multi-part form with multiple tabs for different sections. Right now I have it where there are multiple tabs and the "Next" and "Prev" button switches to the next tab.
The problem I'm having is how to merge my validation with my multiple tabs.
Thanks.

```
<div class="tabbable">
    <form class="form-horizontal" id="validation-form" method="POST" action="Fanalisis/analisisProses.php">
        <div id="tabs">
           <ul class="nav nav-tabs padding-18">
                <li class="active">
                    <a data-toggle="tab" href="#lokasi">
                        <i class="green icon-location-arrow bigger-120"></i>
                        Lokasi dan Pasokan Air Minimum
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li>
                   <a data-toggle="tab" href="#laju">
                       <i class="orange icon-bolt bigger-120"></i>
                       Laju Penerapan Air
                   </a>
                </li>

                <li>
                   <a data-toggle="tab" href="#potensi">
                      <i class="blue icon-anchor bigger-120"></i>
                      Potensi Pengangkutan Air
                   </a>
                </li>

                <li>
                   <a data-toggle="tab" href="#result">
                       <i class="pink icon-fire-extinguisher bigger-120"></i>
                       Result
                   </a>
                 </li>
            </ul>

            <div class="tab-content no-border padding-24">
             <!--LOKASI-->
                <div id="lokasi" class="tab-pane in active">
                     ....
                     <div class="hr hr10 hr-double"></div>\

                          <ul class="pager pull-right">

                              <li class="previous disabled">

                                 <a class="prevtab" href="#">&larr; Prev</a>
                              </li>

                               <li class="next">
                                  <a class="nexttab" href="#laju">Next &rarr;</a>
                               </li>
                           </ul>
                       </div>
                       <!--END LOKASI-->
                       <!--LAJU-->

                       <div id="laju" class="tab-pane">
                           ...
                       <div class="hr hr10 hr-double"></div>

                       <ul class="pager pull-right">
                           <li class="previous">
                               <a class="prevtab" href="#lokasi">&larr; Prev</a>
                           </li>

                           <li class="next">
                               <a class="nexttab" href="#potensi">Next &rarr;</a>
                           </li>
                       </ul>
                   </div>
                   <!--END LAJU-->
                   <!--POTENSI-->
                   <div id="potensi" class="tab-pane">
                       ...

                       <div class="hr hr10 hr-double"></div>

                       <ul class="pager pull-right">
                           <li class="previous">
                                <a class="prevtab" href="#laju">&larr; Prev</a>
                           </li>

                           <li class="next">
                                <a class="nexttab" href="#result">Next &rarr;</a>
                           </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!--END POTENSI-->
                    <!--RESULT-->
                    <div id="result" class="tab-pane">
                        ....
                    <div class="form-actions">
                        <div class="pull-right">
                            <button class="btn">
                                <i class="icon-arrow-left bigger-110"></i>
                                Kembali
                            </button>

                             &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                             <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">
                                 <i class="icon-ok"></i>
                                  Submit
                              </button>
                         </div>
                    </div>
               </div>
               <!--END RESULT-->
               </div>
           </div>
      </form>
 </div>
```

this tabs "next" and "prev" code.

```
$('.nexttab').click(function() {
    $('.nav-tabs > .active').next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
});

$('.prevtab').click(function() {
    $('.nav-tabs > .active').prev('li').find('a').trigger('click');
});
```

this my validation code.

```
$(function() {
            $('#validation-form').show();
            //documentation : http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate
            $('#validation-form').validate({
                errorElement: 'span',
                errorClass: 'help-block',
                focusInvalid: false,
                rules: {
                    kecamatan: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    nama_tipe_baru1: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    nilai_tipe_baru1: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    nama_tipe_baru2: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    nilai_tipe_baru2: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    desa: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    sumber_air_: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    exposure: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    tipe_proteksi: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    nilai_bangunan1: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    nilai_bangunan2: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    angka_kostruksi1: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    angka_kostruksi2: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    tinggi1: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    tinggi2: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    tepol: {
                        required: true
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    kecamatan: "Mohon untuk memilih lokasi kecamatan.",
                    desa: "Mohon untuk memilih lokasi desa.",
                    sumber_air_: "Mohon untuk memilih sumber air.",
                    tipe_proteksi: "Mohon untuk memilih tipe proteksi kebakaran.",
                    exposure: "Mohon untuk memilih.",
                    tepol: "Mohon untuk memilih."
                },
                invalidHandler: function(event, validator) { //display error alert on form submit   
                    $('.alert-error', $('.login-form')).show();
                },
                highlight: function(e) {
                    $(e).closest('.control-group').removeClass('info').addClass('error');
                },
                success: function(e) {
                    $(e).closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('info');
                    $(e).remove();
                },
                errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                    if (element.is(':checkbox') || element.is(':radio')) {
                        var controls = element.closest('.controls');
                        if (controls.find(':checkbox,:radio').length > 1)
                            controls.append(error);
                        else
                            error.insertAfter(element.nextAll('.lbl:eq(0)').eq(0));
                    }
                    else if (element.is('.select2')) {
                        error.insertAfter(element.siblings('[class*="select2-container"]:eq(0)'));
                    }
                    else if (element.is('.chzn-select')) {
                        error.insertAfter(element.siblings('[class*="chzn-container"]:eq(0)'));
                    }
                    else
                        error.insertAfter(element);
                },
                submitHandler: function(form) {
                    var url = "Fanalisis/analisisProses.php";

                    // mengambil nilai dari inputbox, textbox dan select
                    var v_kec = $('select[name=kecamatan]').val();
                    var v_air = $('select[name=sumber_air]').val();
                    var v_desa = $('select[name=desa]').val();
                    var v_bangunan1 = $('input:text[name=nilai_bangunan1]').val();
                    var v_bangunan2 = $('input:text[name=nilai_bangunan2]').val();
                    var v_akons1 = $('select[name=angka_konstruksi1]').val();
                    var v_akons2 = $('select[name=angka_konstruksi2]').val();
                    var v_tinggi1 = $('input:text[name=tinggi1]').val();
                    var v_tinggi2 = $('input:text[name=tinggi2]').val();
                    var v_exposure = $('input:radio[name=exposure]').val();
                    var v_tepol = $('input:radio[name=tepol]').val();
                    //var v_hasil1 = $('input:text[name=hasil1]').val();
                    //var v_hasil2 = $('input:text[name=hasil2]').val();

                    $.post(url, {tinggi2: v_tinggi2, desa: v_desa, kecamatan: v_kec, sumber_air: v_air, nilai_bangunan1: v_bangunan1, nilai_bangunan2: v_bangunan2, angka_konstruksi1: v_akons1, angka_konstruksi2: v_akons2, tinggi1: v_tinggi1, exposure: v_exposure, tepol: v_tepol, hasil1: v_hasil1, hasil2: v_hasil2}, function() {

                    })
                },
                invalidHandler: function(form) {
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what you're asking? Is the validation working? Are you asking how to merge your tab logic with your validation logic?

Comment: @bencripps : sorry my bad, my validation is working, how to merge my tab logic with my validation logic.

Comment: Have you tried just merging the code into one `$(document).ready()` call?

Comment: @bencripps : I've done it and not working, but what I want is when there is one of the html tags (input, textarea, etc.) that have not filled, then the next tab will be disabled.

Comment: You should create a function that runs your validation, rather than use the anony func you have here: here's a tiny example just using jQuery; http://jsfiddle.net/9h26nh3b/

Comment: @bencripps : thanks, but i still have a problem with how to merge that two logic.